# How to insert query into mysql with single quotes

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert, single-quotes

I want to insert a query into a database which contain single quotes within the value. How can I handle this in PHP?

My query is:

```
insert into query (date_time, userid, user_traits, query_sql, status, description, is_scheduled_row) 
values ('2016-01-06 02:39:01', '307', '0,3598,1937,13891,37746,22082,2596,2431,12850,3917,1234784,44712,14638,14418,12850,2631,25003,11428,27450,2592,23593,11441,2826,36330,32219,32351,20720,13997,2594,2467,15687', 'Select * from gl_base_schema.item where national_status_cd = 'A'', 'in queue', ' (Scheduled Query #413) Pull all items where National Status Code is 'A'', 1);
```

It shows error as

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'A'', 'in queue', ' (Scheduled Query #413) Pull all items where National Status C' at line 1
```

Comment: use addslashes() php function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your **single quote(')** in value to **BackSlash & Single Quote (\')** or **two single quotes ('')**

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO QUERY (date_time, userid, user_traits, query_sql, STATUS, description, is_scheduled_row) 
VALUES ('2016-01-06 02:39:01', '307', '0,3598,1937,13891,37746,22082,2596,2431,12850,3917,1234784,44712,14638,14418,12850,2631,25003,11428,27450,2592,23593,11441,2826,36330,32219,32351,20720,13997,2594,2467,15687', 'Select * from gl_base_schema.item where national_status_cd = ''A''', 'in queue', ' (Scheduled Query #413) Pull all items where National Status Code is ''A''', 1);
```

**OR**

```
INSERT INTO QUERY (date_time, userid, user_traits, query_sql, STATUS, description, is_scheduled_row) 
VALUES ('2016-01-06 02:39:01', '307', '0,3598,1937,13891,37746,22082,2596,2431,12850,3917,1234784,44712,14638,14418,12850,2631,25003,11428,27450,2592,23593,11441,2826,36330,32219,32351,20720,13997,2594,2467,15687', 'Select * from gl_base_schema.item where national_status_cd = \'A\'', 'in queue', ' (Scheduled Query #413) Pull all items where National Status Code is \'A\'', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "Select * from gl_base_schema.item where national_status_cd = 'A'";
$sql = "insert into query (date_time, userid, user_traits, query_sql, status, description, is_scheduled_row) values ('2016-01-06 02:39:01', '307', '0,3598,1937,13891,37746,22082,2596,2431,12850,3917,1234784,44712,14638,14418,12850,2631,25003,11428,27450,2592,23593,11441,2826,36330,32219,32351,20720,13997,2594,2467,15687', '."'".$query."'".', 'in queue', ' (Scheduled Query #413) Pull all items where National Status Code is \'A\'', 1)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that with **double** and **single quote** combination:

```
insert into query (date_time, userid, user_traits, query_sql, status, description, is_scheduled_row) 
VALUES ("2016-01-06 02:39:01","307","0,3598,1937,13891,37746,22082,2596,2431,12850,3917,1234784,44712,14638,14418,12850,2631,25003,11428,27450,2592,23593,11441,2826,36330,32219,32351,20720,13997,2594,2467,15687","Select * from gl_base_schema.item where national_status_cd = 'A'","in queue"," (Scheduled Query #413) Pull all items where National Status Code is 'A'", 1)
```

You can use `'A'` this string into another string than you can use this as `"'A' test"`

Answer (score -1):

Where you have `'A''`, make it `'A'''`. The extra `'` escapes the next `'`, so you need `''` for one `'`. Hope that helps.